# Java - Set<ObjectA> removeAll(Set<ObjectB>) does not do its job

Tags: java, set

I have got a Set A, and a Set B. What I want to do is Set A - set B by using 
Set A.removeAll(Set B).

I have already overrided both equals() and hashCode() function as follows:

## GooleGeometryPoint.class

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 31) // two randomly chosen prime numbers
                    .append(postalcode)
                    .toHashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    if (!(obj instanceof GoogleGeometryPoint))
        return false;
    if (obj == this)
        return true;

    if(postalcode.equals(((GoogleGeometryPoint) obj).getPostalcode())) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

## Main.class

```
Set<GoogleGeometryPoint> onlinePostalcodes;
Set<GoogleGeometryPoint> offlinePostalcodes;

//Get all complaints
        complaints =
                CsvParser.parseCsv(Constants.FILE_KLACHTEN_CSV)
                        .stream()
                        .map(k -> CsvParser.mapToKlachtModel(k.toString()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

        //Get all offline postalcodes with coordinates
        offlinePostalcodes =
                CsvParser.parseCsv(Constants.FILE_POSTAL_CSV)
                        .stream()
                        .map(p -> CsvParser.mapToGoogleGeometryPoint(p.toString()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());


        //Copy complaints into set
        onlinePostalcodes = complaints
                .stream()
                .map(e -> new GoogleGeometryPoint(e.getPostalcode(), e.getStreet(), e.getCity()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());


        //Remove all the postalcodes that are already offline available
        onlinePostalcodes
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getPostalcode() != null)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet())
                .removeAll(offlinePostalcodes);
```

After calling the removeAll() method, onlinePostalcodes seems to contain the same objects as before, nothing is removed. Is there anything wrong with my logic? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the type of ```postalcode``` ?

Comment: It is a String, but answer of JF Meier fixed it. I will chose it as accepted answer. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `.collect(Collectors.toSet())` you create a new object from which you delete. You do not change `onlinePostalcodes`. Maybe you intended to write

```
    onlinePostalcodes = onlinePostalcodes
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getPostalcode() != null)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    onlinePostalcodes.removeAll(offlinePostalcodes);
```

Comment: If my answer solves the problem, please accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I will. But stack wont let me. I have to wait 5 minutes.